# Concatenate string from row below

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following example dataframe:

```
+------+--------------+
| item |    client    |
+------+--------------+
| 1    | client       |
| NaN  |  name1       |
| 2    | client       |
| Nan  |  name2       |
| 1    | client name3 |
| 4    | client       |
| Nan  |  name4       |
+------+--------------+
```

If the `item` is NaN, the string in the `client` column needs to be concatenated with the string in the row above. The expected output is

```
+------+--------------+
| item |    client    |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | client name1 |
|    2 | client name2 |
|    1 | client name3 |
|    4 | client name4 |
+------+--------------+
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
data = [[1, 'client'], [np.nan, ' name1'], [2, 'client'], [np.nan, ' name2'], [1, 
'client name3'], [4, 'client'], [np.nan, ' name4']] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Item', 'Client'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ffill` to fill the `NaN` values with the previous rows, then `groupby()` to join the strings. Something like this:

```
df.groupby(df['Item'].ffill())['Client'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()
```

For the updated case, use `notnull()` and `cumsum()`:

```
df.groupby(df['Item'].notna().cumsum()).agg({
    'Item':'first',
    'Client': ' '.join
})
```

Output:

```
      Item         Client
Item                     
1      1.0  client  name1
2      2.0  client  name2
3      1.0   client name3
4      4.0  client  name4
```

Comment: What is the output of this? It doesnt seem to be in a Dataframe with denominated headers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A little thing I didnt think would cause an issue but does. It is actually possible for mulitple rows to have the same 'item' number (see edit), so grouping by that is not option. Any work arounds?